# How can I get a reference to a Kotlin KClass by name when not running on the JVM?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

When targeting Javascript and native `java.lang.Class.forName()` is not available. How can I get a `KClass` in these environments?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because for some reason I've missed the JavaScript part of the question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

As it said in **Kotlin** [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-reflection.html):

> At this time, **JavaScript** does not support the full **Kotlin** reflection
>   API. The only supported part of the API is the `::class` syntax which
>   allows you to refer to the class of an instance, or the class
>   corresponding to the given type. The value of a `::class` expression is
>   a stripped-down `KClass` implementation that only supports the
>   `simpleName` and `isInstance` members.

Here's the example:

```
val a = A()

print(a::class.simpleName)  // Obtains class for an instance; prints "A"
print(A::class.simpleName)  // Obtains class for a type; prints "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it on Native nor JavaScript version (it does work on the JVM one) but you can just do `SomeClass::class`. [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references)